# Change width of tk Combobox dropdown scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, width, scrollbar

Is it possible to change the width of a tk Combobox scrolldown bar in python 2.7? I'm not talking about the combobox width, but rather the scrollbar width on the combobox that appears when the combobox is active.  For example:

```
self.cmbSortOrder=ttk.Combobox(self.frame2, value=l, textvariable=self.SortOrder)
self.cmbSortOrder.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.reloadList)
self.cmbSortOrder.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `configure()`: This class is used to manipulate the style database.

Syntax:

```
configure(style, query_opt=None, **kw)
```

> Query or set the default value of the specified option(s) in style.
>
> Each key in kw is an option and each value is a string identifying the
>   value for that option.
>
> For example, to change every default button to be a flat button with
>   some padding and a different background color do:

```
ttk.Style().configure("TButton", padding=6, relief="flat",background="#ccc")
```

in your case you can do:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
import ttk
root = Tk()

dropdown_width = 100
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('TCombobox', postoffset=(0, 0, dropdown_width, 0))

value_list = ['list value 1', 'list value 2']
c = ttk.Combobox(root, values=value_list)
c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: ncica, doesn't that just change the width of the Combobox list, and not the width of the list scrollbar when the Combobox is activated?  I am trying to change the width of the actual scrollbar, not the width of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The Combobox widget leverages the Scrollbar widget, thus changing the style of the Scrollbar widget will be observable by instances of the Combobox widget. A crude example below shows this:

```
# Create a style instance
style = ttk.Style()

# Specify style the preference(s) for combo box widgets
style.configure( 'TCombobox', arrowsize=25 )

# Alter the template properties of the scroll bar to affect the Combobox widget
style.configure( 'Vertical.TScrollbar', width=22 )
style.configure( 'Vertical.TScrollbar', arrowsize =22 )
style.configure( 'Vertical.TScrollbar', arrowsize =22 )
```