# How to show full text in a Combobox Listbox, because of short width of the Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am working on tkinter, and I have a question how to read missing letters becuase of short length of combobox.

[image: Screenshot]
The actual values in the combobox are:

```
 "IV_#10_fullblank2_edit.kdf_Die1"
 "IV_#10_fullblank2_edit.kdf_Die8"
```

However, because the width of the `Listbox` is not width enough, values are seen only partly.

What I want to do here is that, when I move my mouse on the value, I want to see the whole item entry so that I **don`t need to change width** or orders or widgets.

I've seen many times that when I move my mouse on some `Combobox`, it shows an additional block including explanation or some information.

Comment: ***"shows an additional block"***: You mean a `Tooltip` popup window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change-width-of-tk-combobox-dropdown-scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718769/change-width-of-tk-combobox-dropdown-scrollbar)